# bash script for interproscan REST

Tags: bash

hey i have the problem with bash script. It should run interproscan REST
Im green in bash scripting. I found this script on the [web](https://gist.github.com/terrymun/889f28314643d429496881adbdd40039):

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
waitevery=30

mkdir -p out

for j in $(find `pwd` -type f -name "*.fa")
do
    echo "Iteration: $i; File: $j"
    filename=$(basename "$j")
    python3 iprscan5.py \
        --goterms \
        --pathways \
        --email=blabla@protonmail.com \
        --outfile=out/${filename} \
        --outformat=tsv \
        --quiet \
        $j & (( i++%waitevery==0 )) && wait
done
```

out:

```
Iteration: 1; File: /home/marcin/interproscan-5.57-90.0-64-bit/interproscan-5.57-90.0/test/xtr.fa
interpro_batch_submit.sh: 18: i++%waitevery==0: not found
Iteration: 1; File: /home/marcin/interproscan-5.57-90.0-64-bit/interproscan-5.57-90.0/test/xts.fa
interpro_batch_submit.sh: 18: i++%waitevery==0: not found
Iteration: 1; File: /home/marcin/interproscan-5.57-90.0-64-bit/interproscan-5.57-90.0/test/xtt.fa
interpro_batch_submit.sh: 18: i++%waitevery==0: not found
Iteration: 1; File: /home/marcin/interproscan-5.57-90.0-64-bit/interproscan-5.57-90.0/test/xtu.fa
interpro_batch_submit.sh: 18: i++%waitevery==0: not found
Iteration: 1; File: /home/marcin/interproscan-5.57-90.0-64-bit/interproscan-5.57-90.0/test/xtv.fa
interpro_batch_submit.sh: 18: i++%waitevery==0: not found
Iteration: 1; File: /home/marcin/interproscan-5.57-90.0-64-bit/interproscan-5.57-90.0/test/xtw.fa
```

Edit:

I think I forgot to add `--sequence`, but something was still wrong after it.

Comment: Also, I'm assuming you're saving the script as `submit.sh` and then running it. How are you running it exactly?

Comment: @RamRS `wait` will wait until all background jobs have finished. `(( i++%waitevery==0 ))` will be true whenever the current value of `i` modulo `waitevery` is 0, so this is a really neat trick to make the script wait for all background processes to execute every N processes. Quite clever, that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all *never* do `for foo in $(find ...)`. That is very bad practice as it can't handle even slightly odd file names like those with a space. See [bash pitfall #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Next, you don't need `pwd`, just run `find -type f -name "*.fa"` which will search in the current directory by default and unlike `` find `pwd`... `` , won't break if your path contains whitespace.

That's just general best practice, the real issue here is that you are probably running the script like this:

```
sh /path/to/script.sh
```

Right? And you are using a Debian-based system like Ubuntu, right? On such systems, `/bin/sh` is actually not bash but a very basic POSIX compatible shell called `dash` and `dash` doesn't understand the `(( i++%waitevery==0 ))` syntax.

Since you have a shebang line (`#!/bin/bash`), you can simply make your script executable (`chmod a+x /path/to/script.sh`) and then run the script directly like this:

```
/path/to/script.sh
```

Or, alternatively, run it explicitly with `bash` instead of `sh`:

```
bash /path/to/script.sh
```

Either should work and if your file names and paths are sane, the issues I mentioned above won't be relevant. But to keep things nice and clean, I would also change the script to (note that this assumes you are using Linux and GNU `find`):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
i=1
waitevery=30

mkdir -p out

find -type f -name "*.fa" -print0 |
  while IFS= read -r -d '' j; do 
    echo "Iteration: $i; File: $j"
    filename=$(basename "$j")
    python3 iprscan5.py \
        --goterms \
        --pathways \
        --email="blabla@protonmail.com" \
        --outfile=out/"$filename" \
    --outformat=tsv \
    --quiet \
    "$j" & (( i++%waitevery==0 )) && wait
done
```

Comment: I asked them how they're running 'submit.sh` for the reason you picked precisely - they're probably using `sh` and hitting a POSIX compatibility wall.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that the specific error that's coming up is because there are spaces missing from the wait line. This seems to be a problem in the source script, i.e.:

```
$j & (( i++%waitevery==0 )) && wait
```

should probably be:

```
$j & (( i++ % waitevery == 0 )) && wait
```

but for me (following @terdon's reproduction advice via `dash -c "i=9; ((++i%5==0)) && echo 'worked!'"`) that only changes the thing that is not found from `i++%waitevery==0` to `i++`, suggesting that the post-increment operator is not supported in the shell. Post-increment *is* [supported in bash](https://linuxhint.com/bash_operator_examples/#o13), suggesting that this script is being run (as @RamRS commented) in an unexpected way.

Try running the script directly:

```
./interpro_batch_submit.sh
```

Or explicitly using bash:

```
bash ./interpro_batch_submit.sh
```

... but see @terdon's answer for a better approach to doing this.